# Trying to build a C# ASP.NET app. with the help of which I want to access the Windows CleanUp Utility tool and remove the entry of installed product.

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, windows

**Hi, I want to programmatically access the Windows CleanUP utility tool and remove entries using a C# ASP.NET application. Is this possible and if yes then can someone guide me through this. Thanks.**

Comment: Seriously? [Read this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), try again.

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer would love to hear an answer instead of pointing out my "etiquette"

Comment: Of course you would, but StackOverflow isn't a code writing service. Unless you play by the rules and share what you have tried, your chances of getting an answer are slim.

Answer (score 0):

Use following code in your c# application.

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("<<Call Utility EXE>>");
```